# $A \Longrightarrow \tilde A$ is always false? Tautology problem?

Tags: logic

$A \Longrightarrow \tilde A$ is always false? So here's what I did:

I did the contrapositive $\tilde(\tilde A) = A \Longrightarrow \tilde A$ So by contrapositive, I also get $A$ implies $\tilde A$. I also did a truth table. But I don't get a tautology or contradiction. So it can't always be false. Correct?

Comment: The statement $A\implies\neg A$ is satisfiable when $A$ is false.

Comment: Truth table shows that the sentence $A\implies B$ is true whenever $A$ is false. Replace $B$ by $\bar{A}$. You are right, the sentence  is not always false.

Comment: .. When $A=false$, $A \to \lnot A$ is $true$

Comment: Note that the contraositive manipulation does not *show* that the sentence is sometimes true.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't always false. Suppose $A$ is false, so $\tilde A$ is true. Then "$A\implies\tilde A$" is true; any implication with a false protasis is always a truth ("if the moon is made of blue cheese, then pigs can fly" is a true statement).

Answer (score 1):

No, $A \rightarrow \lnot A$ is **not** always *false*.

It is simply :

> $\lnot A$.

Answer (score 1):

$A \rightarrow \neg A$
is equivalent to
$\neg A \vee \neg A$
which is equivalent to $\neg A$

$(A \rightarrow \neg A) \Leftrightarrow \neg A$

Another way to see it is that the original formula is false if $\neg A$ is true but $A$ isn't. This is when $A$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

It can seem confusing (It did to me at the time), because you might mistakenly $assert$ $A$ when you look at $A \to \lnot A$ without noticing ;-)

Comment: When you says "$A \rightarrow B$" you are **not** asserting $A$ : you are asserting the *conditional* "if $A$, then $B$" ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I know that. I'm just saying this could be a source for confusion.